# How to delete item in WPF-treeview with ItemsSource?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I am a little new in WPF so you can find my question a little strange.
Imagine, we have some class:

```
public class ItemOfWorld
{
    public ObservableCollection<ItemOfWorld> Items { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual void AddItem() { }
    public ItemOfWorld()
    {
        this.Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemOfWorld>();
    }
}

public class Molecules : ItemOfWorld
{
    public Molecules(): base()
    {
        Name = "Molecules";
    }

    public override void AddItem()
    {
        this.Items.Add(new Molecule());
    }
}
```

Then I have HierarchicalDataTemplate in TreeVew like this:

```
HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type pcsadd:ItemOfWorld}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Items.Count}" Foreground="Blue" />
                    </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

The problem is: How can I delete SelectedItem's Object (in this case with ItemOfWorld's type, so `MyTreeView.Items.Remove(MyTreeView.SelectedItem)` will not work)? I have tried:

1. to get parent node of selected item (for example, Molecules is parent node for Molecule), but there are no methods in wpf-TreeVew to get parent node.
2. MyTreeView.Items.Remove(MyTreeView.SelectedItem) - error: Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use
3. Add additional field in my ItemOfWorld class: `public ItemOfWorld Parent;`which will be used like pointer to parent class. I thought it may solve this problem like this: `(MyTreeVew.SelectedItem as ItemOfWorld).Parent.Items.Remove(MyTreeVew.SelectedItem);` but for my application number of molecules is going to be very big, so it will be better if I try to avoid this kind of "solution" and I hope to find with your help more intelligent solution!

   Maybe I have to change ItemsSource link somehow? Any tips or ideas would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: why this dint work? MyTreeVew.Items.Remove(MyTreeVew.SelectedItem);

Comment: Because I am using ItemsSource in DataTemplate, so, when I try to do this I have error: Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use

Comment: @user3742076 so please add such information to your question, like what you have already tried so far and problems you already encountered

Comment: If you are binding to ItemsSource, so remove it from that list.

Comment: ^^Use caution on verbiage. The ItemsSource property is not a list; it merely implements IEnumerable, therefore Add(), and Remove() are not present.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your item from the `ObservableCollection` Directly:

```
Items.Remove(MyTreeView.SelectedItem);
```

Comment: Yes, I agree, but the thing is I have not linnear Collection. I have to find parent ItemOfWorld, which have my SelectedItem and delete it directly. How then can I find parent item of SelectedItem - there is no such methods in WPF-TreeView...Write my own methods with loops and Items.Count() is not good idea..

Comment: Do you have a reference for the `ObservableCollection` that populates your `TreeView`?

Comment: Yes, I have `using System.Collections.ObjectModel;` if I understand you correct )

Comment: No, I mean where do you populate your `TreeView`? (`MyTreeView.ItemsSource = ?`)

Comment: Ok, I have created property of this TreeView and set it in MainWindow form. I have to say, that Add new element and Clean (another methods of my own TreeView toolbox) works without any problems. But I am steel confused with delete of Selected element

Answer (score -2):

Ok, guys, I think I found solution of this problem. The main idea - in WPF-TreeView some methods are really missing and there are no reason for it. So, we have to design it. I have found  good guy, who has already written some additional expanding methods: [thank you, mister Reinhard Ostermeier!](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36193/WPF-TreeView-tools). His library provides possibility to get parent item to other item.

But I have a question about it. Is it ok, if I will keep pointer to parent class in each children? In this case I mean add field to ItemOfWorld class (see question №3): `public ItemOfWorld Parent`. If we try to compare these two solutions (memory using, speed, etc.) - what is better?